# X509 store can not find certificate

Tags: .net, x509

I am using following code to find certificates in personal store. It finds the certificate on first page load but after postback it doen't find the same certificate.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205295/get-list-of-certificates-from-the-certificate-store-in-c/6830696#6830696

Comment: This code is incomplete -- all it does is open the store (which should be .Close(d) when done)