# How to find in store the certificate I need?

Tags: c#, api, x509certificate, certificate-store

For one of my applications I am developing against the TeleCashAPI (Internet Payment Gateway). I need to send a client certificate (p12) on each call.

Until now I have loaded the Client Certificate via Filesystem

```
public void AddCertificate(X509Certificate certificate)
{
    WebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
}
```

Now my customer want to have it more generic. It should be installed on the client machine (which is talking to this api). I still know what is the password, but I don't know the certificate.

How can I get the Certificate?

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205295/get-list-of-certificates-from-the-certificate-store-in-c-sharp), I see how I can get the whole list:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My");

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates){
    //TODO's
}
```

But how I find the certificate I specificly want to have? Is this even posssible?

I am realy new to this topic.

---

To be a little bit more clear:

The certificate is installed by doubleclick. I can not controll this process. My Task is, to find the certificate, which is for TeleCash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know certificate hash - double click on certificate -> details -> Thumbprint

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
{
    if(mCert.Thumbprint.ToLower()=="Your Certificat hash")
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the Certificate Hash? I only now, that someone have installed the certificate, but has no controlling about, how it is installed. I only now, it must be a certificate, which is signed for TeleCash.

Comment: to know certificate hash - double click on certificate -> details -> Thumbprint

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much. I think this should be communicateable.