# How do I verify in .NET a file's signature if it is stored in system's catalogs store

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, digital-signature

For embedded signatures I can use `X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile` to extract the certificate.

What is the .Net way to extract the certificate for a file in the system's store?

X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile is throwing exception for those file!

Comment: Why do you have a file in the System Store? Why not just the Certificate.

Comment: @jdweng   i m validating some files which are in c:\windows\system32 .  They are signed but dont have embedded digital signature.  How to extract certificate for those file

Comment: Can't you use X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile?

Comment: @jdweng no that is not working

Comment: Why?  May be the certificate is bad.

Comment: its Microsoft file. using sigcheck/signtool its showing certificate

Comment: The signtool is doing the CreateFromSignedFile and showing valid signature.  You just have a file and must run create the signature from the file.

Comment: @jdweng with sigcheck also its showing

Comment: file is signed and have a certificate in its catalog. how can i use that certificate?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205295/get-list-of-certificates-from-the-certificate-store-in-c-sharp

Comment: What command are you running that you can’t replicate? What is its output? Both of these, together, will greatly inform the proper answer. (Please edit them into the question)