# Using C# to get a Remote Desktop certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, rdp

I am not sure if this is the correct place to post this and if not please feel free to direct me.

I am looking to get the certificate expiration date of a terminal server.
I can find it manualy [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGXuN.png):

I would like to automate this proccess of finding the expiration date of the certificate preferably from outside of the server on my computer.

In some cases the TS would be a local IP and for other cases their is a url link to the remote desktop.

If it can only be done from within the server I can make that work.

Are there any suggestions as to where i can find some information to set this up?

Any help is much aprechiated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of certificates from the certificate store in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205295/get-list-of-certificates-from-the-certificate-store-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @MarcelO did you find a solution for grabbing the RDP certificate over a network yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload using below link;

[X509Store overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07btzah(v=vs.110).aspx)

Replace the remote server path: \YourRemoteServerName\My in the storeName parameter.